# A microSD card backup (Raspberry Pi) has always a corrupt ext4 filesystem although the original seems to be fine

Tags: filesystems, ext4, dd, sd-card, loop-device

Every backup image of my Raspberry Pi microSD card seems to be corrupt. It doesn't make a difference if I create an image file or if I backup the microSD card directly to some other microSD card.

I've already tried different approaches.
Backup commands already used:

```
dd if=/dev/sde of=pi.img
cat /dev/sde > pi.img
dd if=/dev/sde2 of=pi_part2.img
dd if=/dev/sde2 of=pi_part2.img oflag=dsync bs=64k
pv /dev/sde > /dev/sdf
```

Running fsck on the original filesystem shows no errors:

```
fsck.ext4 -fnv /dev/sde2
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

      169390 inodes used (17.63%, out of 960992)
         686 non-contiguous files (0.4%)
         153 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 159486/127
     2576756 blocks used (67.10%, out of 3840256)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

      141540 regular files
       17848 directories
          30 character device files
           0 block device files
           2 fifos
          53 links
        9898 symbolic links (9674 fast symbolic links)
          63 sockets
------------
      169434 files
```

I've tried running fsck on the new microSD card, directly on the image file, on the loop device created with losetup and on the loop device created with kpartx. The result is always the same and independent of whether it is an image of the partition or the whole drive.

```
losetup -vf pi.img
or
kpartx -a pi.img
or 
losetup -vf pi_part2.img
or
kpartx -a pi_part2.img
```

```
fsck.ext4 -fnv /dev/sdf2
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 651592 has an invalid extent node (blk 2661556, lblk 0)
Clear? no

Inode 651592 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 651592, i_blocks is 200, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 652399 has an invalid extent node (blk 2656133, lblk 0)
Clear? no

Inode 652399 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 652399, i_blocks is 96, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 653587 has an invalid extent node (blk 2655215, lblk 0)
Clear? no

Inode 653587 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 653587, i_blocks is 51776, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 781825 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 781825 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 781825 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

...

Directories count wrong for group #99 (275, counted=0).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (791602, counted=786221).
Fix? no


/dev/sdf2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


      169390 inodes used (17.63%, out of 960992)
         592 non-contiguous files (0.3%)
         140 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 134099/114
     2576756 blocks used (67.10%, out of 3840256)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

      118579 regular files
       15409 directories
          30 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
  4294967090 links
        8110 symbolic links (7886 fast symbolic links)
          58 sockets
------------
      142315 files
```

It gives 1093872 lines of errors.

I've already tried using alternative superblocks.
I've tried saving the image on ext4 of zfs filesystem.
I've tried making an image and putting it on a new microSD card.
I've tried making a direct copy (cat) to other microSD card, taking the card out and sliding a write lock on the adapter to make 100% sure nothing can be changed afterwards.

The result is always the same.

Mounting the original filesystem and making an rsync backup works flawlessly.

**Edit:**
The filesystem on the SD card was definitely not in use while making an image/backup. It was not mounted and there was no blocks written or read according to iostat. I also used two different PCs for the job. One with Kali and a built-in card reader, the other one with Debian Buster and an external USB card reader.

**Edit:**
I've partitioned and created equivalent filesystems on a clean microSD card, then populated it with files. The backup image, created as described above, doesn't have any errors. There must be something wrong with the original microSD card or the original ext4 filesystem. Why wouldn't fsck show any errors and mounting and using the filesystem poses no problems?

**Edit:**
The version of e2fsck is pretty new (the newest one from Debian Buster):

```
e2fsck -V
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
    Using EXT2FS Library version 1.44.5, 15-Dec-2018
```

The command used for the check was mainly `fsck.ext4`. Sometimes I tried `e2fsck`. It makes no difference.

**Edit:**

```
mount | grep /dev/sde
/dev/sde2 on /mnt/oldpi type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=1024)
```

```
blkid /dev/sde
/dev/sde: PTUUID="21f74a8c" PTTYPE="dos"
```

```
blkid | grep /dev/sde
/dev/sde1: UUID="4B06-547E" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="21f74a8c-01"
/dev/sde2: UUID="e6935217-65c8-44be-bde3-79d93b146920" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="21f74a8c-02"
```

**Edit:**
Making two independent images results in identical images:

```
sha256sum *
da464bf4884c8f5db546637cd3e82c41ddd63d65f91f38ca1ec85af1f71c6757  pi_sdcard_20200404_1.img
da464bf4884c8f5db546637cd3e82c41ddd63d65f91f38ca1ec85af1f71c6757  pi_sdcard_20200404_2.img
```

Making a copy directly on the Raspberry pi in rescue mode and after ro remount results in a usable copy with far fewer errors:

```
fsck.ext4 -nvf /dev/sde2 
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 653587 has an invalid extent node (blk 2655215, lblk 0)
Clear? no

Inode 653587 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 653587, i_blocks is 51776, should be 0.  Fix? no

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -2655215 -(2895872--2896020) -(2898068--2898069) -(2902016--2902036) -(2902038--2902039) -(2902043--2902200) -(2902233--2902297) -(2902330--2902648) -(2902681--2904063) -(2906112--2906552) -(2906554--2906617) -(2906619--2907710) -(2907712--2907775) -(2907777--2907840) -(2907842--2908115) -(2908117--2908871) -(2908873--2908936) -(2908938--2909256) -(2909258--2909321) -(2909323--2909386) -(2909388--2909451) -(2909453--2909516) -(2909518--2909581) -(2909583--2909646) -(2909648--2909711) -(2909713--2909776) -(2909778--2909841) -(2909843--2909906) -(2909908--2909971) -(2909973--2910036) -(2910038--2910207) -(2912405--2912406) -(2914448--2914455) -(2916498--2916504) -(2943123--2943129) -(2945171--2945242) -(2945244--2945266) -(2945268--2945331) -(2945333--2945392) -(2945394--2945428) -(2945430--2945441) -(2945472--2945478)
Fix? no


/dev/sde2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


      169390 inodes used (17.63%, out of 960992)
         685 non-contiguous files (0.4%)
         153 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 159485/126
     2575505 blocks used (67.07%, out of 3840256)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

      141539 regular files
       17847 directories
          30 character device files
           0 block device files
           2 fifos
          53 links
        9898 symbolic links (9674 fast symbolic links)
          65 sockets
------------
      169434 files
```

After correcting errors automatically with fsck. Everything seems to be OK.

Is there any way I could debug it or check if microSD card is corrupt?
The most important question for me is: why is this happening and can I rely on this backup method (dd, cat, pv etc.) for SDcards, flash drives etc.?

Comment: Was the filesystem on the SD card in use during image creation?

Comment: Is the version of `e2fsck` on your destination machine recent enough to understand the ext4 filesystem from your source? I also notice you don't use `fsck.ext4` like you did on the source machine - is that relevant?

Comment: This is really weird. It almost appears that when you are copying the backup, you are not reading the same bytes as when you `fsck` or `mount` the original SD.  Could you double check what is reported when you have the original mounted?  Assuming the origional is `/dev/sde` check both `mount | grep /dev/sde` and `blkid /dev/sde`.